# When I pip install pickle I am facing this error error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools":

Tags: python, pickle

I am trying to graph cookies from Facebook. My intension is to using selenium for web automation. I am using pickle to grab cookies.

**Code:**

```
import pickle
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("../chromedriver.exe")

def save_cookies(driver, location):
    pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open(location, "wb"))
cookies_location = "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Campaign\Experiments\cookies.txt"

# Initial load of the domain that we want to save cookies for
chrome = driver
chrome.get("https://www.facebook.com/")

username = os.environ.get('facebook_zrliqi_email')
password = os.environ.get('facebook_zrliqi_pass')

driver.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_name("pass").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_name("login").click()
print(input("Press any Key: "))
print("Login work Successfully ")
save_cookies(chrome, cookies_location)
chrome.quit()
```

But when I try to pip install pickle in my Pycharm. I am fetching it needs to install visual studio tools.

**I got this error:**

```
  building 'pickle5._pickle' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```

Comment: did you install - Microsoft C++ Build Tools

Comment: no I didn't. Let me try.

Comment: pickle is part of python's standard library, it shouldn't need installing.

Comment: Download and install https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/fr/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16

Comment: @tdelaney so why I am getting this error?

Comment: @tdelaney  Now I got this error

 File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Campaign\Experiments\Cookies.py", line 47
    cookies_location = "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Campaign\Experiments\cookies.txt"
                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: @JonyGhosh use "r" before your string.

Comment: @SushenBiswas thank you it's works
cookies_location = r"C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Campaign\Experiments\cookies.txt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

base on that error :

```
"C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Campaign\Experiments\Cookies.py", line 47 cookies_location = "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Campaign\Experiments\cookies.txt" ^ SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

you have a Unicode problem.

```
cookies_location = r"C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Campaign\Experiments\cookies.txt
```

putting **r** before your string solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>**Disclaimer**: I extracted this answer from the OPs question. [Answers should not be contained in the question itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309555/316262).</sub>

---

#### Answer provided by [Jony Ghosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16663945/jony-ghosh):

You don't have to install pickle . Pickle is already in the python standard library. when I was working on that I learnt that.
And thanks to [@tdelaney](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309555/316262) for let me know it's a part of python standard library.